# File request parsing in Flask server is slower when running on Docker image, any solutions?

Tags: docker, flask, deployment, web-applications, gunicorn

I have a React-Flask application and that now I have been running within a docker container for deployment. This app sends large files to the Flask server via FormData (a total of almost 200 MB). To deploy the app I am using gunicorn with the following command:

`gunicorn --workers 6 --timeout 500 --graceful-timeout 500 --bind 0.0.0.0:5001 wsgi:app`

While running locally (either in flask dev-mode or running gunicorn locally) it takes around 3 second to return a request to the client, but when deploying on docker it takes more than 30 seconds.

My OS is a macOS M1. Docker is running using alpine.

Any ideas on why is this being caused? Or any ideas on how to solve it?

I have tried to run the file parsing as an async task in flask, but I keep getting other error messages from it. The code below shows the working version that is "fast" in dev mode but slow in Docker.

```
/**
   * Sends data to the server using a POST request.
   * @function sendDataAsync
   * @returns {void}
   */
  function sendDataAsync() {
    const formData = new FormData();

    genomes.forEach((genome, i) => {
      const { genomefasta, genomeannotation } = genome[`genome${i + 1}`];

      formData.append("genomefasta", genomefasta);

      genomeannotation.forEach((annotation, k) => {
        formData.append(`genomeannotation${i + 1}`, annotation);
      });

      const rep = replicates[i][`genome${i + 1}`];

      rep.forEach((replicate, j) => {
        const letter = String.fromCharCode(97 + j);
        const { enrichedforward, enrichedreverse, normalforward, normalreverse } = replicate[`replicate${letter}`];

        // gather the data into the formData object
      });
    });


    formData.append("alignmentfile", alignmentFile);

    fetch("/api/runAsync/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setLoading([false, false]);

        if (data.result === "success") {
          // open result in new tab
          let filePath = data.id;
          let URL = `/status/${filePath}`
          window.open(URL, "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
        } else {
          console.log(data);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

```py
@app.route('/api/runAsync/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def getInputAsync():
    '''get the input from the form and execute TSS prediction'''
    # save start time
    startTime = time()
    request_files = request.files.to_dict(flat=False) # Only this line takes around 30 sec. 
    result = do_some_process(files)
    # print runnning time
    print("Time: " + str(time() - startTime))
    return jsonify({'result': 'success', "id": result['id']})
```

Comment: You deploy on a VM or k8s?

Comment: Neither, just running it on the same computer where I am running the dev. But your idea with the vcpu's sounds reasonable. Will test it and comment any updates.

Answer (score 0):

when you deploy on a docker container, your server 'll be provided a `fixed number vcpu` that lower your local mechine. It will cause slow performance because workers compete for resources when you use many workers. Example, your container is provided 1 vcpu but your gunicorn run with 6 worker. It 'll slower than your run gunicorn locally that can use full resource.

1. Check your container resource: vcpu, ram
2. Change a number worker that fit for that resource. You can set `--workers 1` and increase to choose the most suitable configuration

Comment: So I was able to identify that the CPU usage goes up, but this is expected. Sadly, the problem itself seems nothing to do with the number of worker, since decreasing the number does not reduce the competition and increasing the CPUs does not improve performance

Comment: @MWP Could you monitor your I/O network and read/write disk. File processing task requires IO network and disk write file. Maybe have a limit when using in docker such as use `--network=host` when run docker image to use full network